# Using Upgrade files in Magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, deploy

In our project 04 different developers have each own environments (Dev, Prod) in Localhost. And we have also 02 Environments in Server (Dev + Prod). My question is:

1-  When 02 developers work in the same time with Theme, and want to deploy into server. How could they synchronize their database to obtain the only database to deploy.?

2- How could we using Upgrade files of Magento to synchronize different database when deploying into server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all every modification required to the database from a specific module should be scripted inside that module. [Here is a simple tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-6-magento-setup-resources) that explains how to add install/upgrade scripts inside a module.
Create a convention between developers for naming the upgrade scripts. Here is how I usually do it.
The person that creates the module will set the module version to `0.0.1` and each new upgrade script just increments the last number in the version. So the install script will be `install-0.0.1.php` and next script will be named `upgrade-0.0.1-0.0.2.php` (and change the version of the module to `0.0.2`). The next one will be `upgrade-0.0.2-0.0.3.php`...and so on.
If someone decides to change the major or minor version (0.1.0 or 1.0.0) he/she should announce it (but so far I had no reason of doing it). This can be changed when creating a tag in the versioning system by the person in charge of creating the tags (but it's not mandatory).

For scripts that require the change of a config setting (for example change the theme name) or adding a new attribute (not used for a specific module) I usually create one simple module that I only use for upgrade scripts and follow the same convention as above.
Of course there will be conflicts, when 2 different developers will create an upgrade script with the same file name. For example: `upgrade-0.0.3-0.0.4.php`. The convention here is *first come first served*.
If you use a versioning system (and you should), before committing the changes a developer should do a checkout of the current committed code. If a file with the name `upgrade-0.0.3-0.0.4.php` already exists, the developer will be forced to change the version number and the upgrade script file name. So the conflicts can be resolved on the dev machine.
If every developer works on a different branch, then maybe each of them should create his/her own extension used only for upgrade scripts.
This has worked for me so far without major conflicts. (Anyway all the conflicts were solved easily and peacefully).

Answer (score 3):

Any `core_config_data` settings can be manipulated with setup scripts. Note that if you want to work with the website or atore scopes you *should* use a data setup script, as these scope values will have been merged into the configuration DOM by then and can be parsed. As a general example, your developers' theme settings can be written using [`Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->setConfigData()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php#L892):

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->setConfigData(
    'design/theme/template', //path
    'custom',                //value
    'websites'               //scope (default, websites, stores) 
    1                        //scope ID
);
$installer->endSetup();
```

It will be up to your team to manage the versions, or you could assign each team member to their own setup module.